# React + webpack dev environment setup - wrong filepath

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to set up a developer environment for React but I'm getting some issues with webpack pathing. Usually, a quick google solves issues like these but I haven't seen anyone with the same problem, which probably means I'm an idiot and is messing something up.

So, I followed a tutorial and I have a `dev`-folder and a `output`-folder. In `output` I have `output.js`, where I want webpack to output all my stuff. So, according to the guide, I should run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack` and it should work with the config I have, but it's showing the wrong filepath. I want it to go to `react-test/output/output.js` but it's throwing in a `/dev`, making it `react-test/dev/output/output.js`. My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DEV = path.resolve(__dirname, "dev");
var OUTPUT = path.resolve(__dirname, "output");

var config = {
  entry: DEV + "/index.jsx",
  output: {
    path: OUTPUT,
    filename: "output.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        include: DEV,
        loader: "babel-loader"
    }]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I can't see where `dev` is getting added.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the file to the following:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/dev/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/output'),
    filename: 'output.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

You don't need to require webpack in this file, but you do need to tell the module loader what to test. The presets I included are assuming you are using ReactJS and ES6, you may need to change them as appropriate.

Comment: I tried this config and I'm still getting the same error -- an added `/dev` in the file path. Very weird!

Comment: Hey Eric, is `react-test` the name of the app or a folder within your app? This configuration expects the `/dev` folder to be in the root of the app.

Answer (score 0):

webpack.config

```
var path = require("path");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    entry: './dev/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'output'),
        filename: 'output.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] }  
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'app/Index.html'  // Copy Index.html with script tag refrencing output.js in Output folder
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set *[context](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context)* option to `react-test` directory.
And set *DEV* and *OUTPUT* paths realtive to it:

```
var DEV = path.resolve(__dirname, "./dev");
var OUTPUT = path.resolve(__dirname, "./output");

var config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
  entry: DEV + "/index.jsx",
  output: {
    path: OUTPUT,
    filename: "output.js"
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, this didn't change anything either, my pathing is still incorrect. Could it be something else I'm missing?

Comment: Just to make sure, isn't this the old file generated previously? Got myself into such case once.